# Rails, Cual es la mejor manera de mostrar en la vista las imagenes previas a cargarla en la bd, con carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polimorfismo

He estado creando una vista en el formulario, el cual tiene imagenes, pero no consigo la forma de mostrar la imagenes previas que estoy seleccionando para dejarlas o quitarlas antes de cargalas a la bd, tanto para crear o para editar. Adjunto mi form y espero su ayuda. Gracias.

```
<div class="row">
 <%= simple_form_for [:admin, @history], validate: true, html: {multiple: true} do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :title, label: "Título", required: true, autofocus: true %>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="form-inputs">
         <%= f.input :description, label: 'Description', as: :text, :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="control-group">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">

       <%= f.fields_for :images_attributes do |images_fields| %>
        Image: <%= images_fields.file_field :image, :multiple => true,name: "images_attributes[image][]" %>

       <% end %>

       <%# f.attachment_field :images_files, multiple: true, presigned: true, direct: true %>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>


 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
   <hr>
   <center>
       <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),  admin_histories_path(:history_status => "publicada"), :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
       <%= f.submit 'Aceptar', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
   </center>
   <p>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Mis modelos son:

image.rb

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

hystory.rb

```
class History < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

   validates :title, presence: true
   validates :description, presence: true
end
```

Teniendo en cuenta que estoy haciendo uso de polimorfismo y que son varias imagenes que estoy subiendo y no sola una.

Comment: ¿pero cuál es el error específico? ¿no te sale el input de tipo file para agregar imágenes? ¿o puedes agregar imágenes y luego no te las muestra? en ese caso ¿verificaste que efectivamente se estén guardando en la bd? ¿por qué tienes un `attachment_field` que es de `refile` cuando se supone que estás usando `carrierwave`? quizás el usar ambas gemas te está dando algún tipo de problema

Comment: No puedo previsualizar las imagenes que estoy subiendo antes de cargarlas.

Comment: @AdrianRama lo que quieres es que cuando del input escojas una imagen se te muestre en la vista del formulario?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuando seleccione las imagenes que quiera subir al formulario que pueden ser una o varias de una sola vez, poder visualizarlas, para ver las imaganes que estoy subiendo.

Comment: Para eso puedes usar jquery file upload, creo que hay gemas que lo integran con rails, aunque desconozco si siguen vigentes para rails 5 (hace bastante tiempo las usé). De seguro que hayan otras alternativas más modernas para usar sin necesidad de jquery, en caso de que no estés usándolo.